# Predict survival score and CLTV for contractual discrete policies/terms

Tags: python, survival-analysis, cox-regression, lifelines, scikit-survival

I am trying to predict the survival score and LTV for contractual and discrete policies(in insurance) in python. I browsed number of sites but I could find many examples only for non-contractual(in retail).
I have used the below code:

```
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter
#After all feature selection and EDA

cph_train, cph_test = train_test_split(features, test_size=0.2)

cph = CoxPHFitter()
cph.fit(cph_train, 'TIME', event_col='EVENT')
cph.print_summary()
```

Where TIME - is number of days between the policy taken date and current date for ACTIVE customers and between policy taken date and surrendered date for nonACTIVE customers.
EVENT - is the indicator for whether the customer is ACTIVE or not ACTIVE.

After fitting the model I got concordance of 0.7(which I feel is OK).
From here on how do I proceed to get survival score for the ACTIVE customers and lifetime value(CLTV)?
Bascially I need to predict who are the valuable customers who will stay for long with the company.

I have added some code by going thru some posts and suggestions by Cam.

```
censored_subjects = features.loc[features['EVENT'] == 1] #Selecting only the ACTIVE ones

unconditioned_sf = cph.predict_survival_function(censored_subjects)

conditioned_sf = unconditioned_sf.apply(lambda c: (c / c.loc[features.loc[c.name, 'TIME']]).clip_upper(1)) 

predictions_75 = qth_survival_times(.75, conditioned_sf)
predictions_50 = qth_survival_times(.50, conditioned_sf)

values = predictions_75.T.join(data[['PREAMT','TIME']])
values50 = predictions_50.T.join(data[['PREAMT','TIME']])
values['RemainingValue'] = values['PREAMT'] * (values[0.75] - values['TIME'])
```

So what does the output denote:
`0.5 PREAMT TIME` --- The number in column 0.5 does it denotes the duration for which there is 50% chance for getting closed?
`0.75 PREAMT TIME` --- Similarly 0.75 denotes the duration for which there is 75% chance for getting closed?
`RemainingValue` --- Is it the remaining amount to be paid?

And what is the next step post-this?

Comment: could you predict customers CLTV?

Answer (score 3):

> Where TIME - is number of days between the policy taken date and current date for ACTIVE customers and between policy taken date and surrendered date for nonACTIVE customers. EVENT - is the indicator for whether the customer is ACTIVE or not ACTIVE.

Makes sense to me.

> After fitting the model I got concordance of 0.7(which I feel is OK).

That's an acceptable score for survival models But also try [AFT models](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html#accelerated-failure-time-models), these might perform better (also try [modelling *all* the parameters](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html#modeling-ancillary-parameters)).

---

So what you need to do next is to predict future lifetime of customers *given* they have survived *t* periods. There are [some docs](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html#prediction) on exactly this application. Note the same code applies to AFT models too.

You can choose to predict the median, or survival curve. If your goal is CLV, I think predicting the survival curve is more appropriate, as you can model varying policy rates (sorry I don't know the correct terminology). For example, using the code in the docs:

```
times = np.arange(1000) # predict far out, since we don't want to truncate the survival curve prematurely. 
unconditioned_sf = cph.predict_survival_function(censored_subjects, times=times)

conditioned_sf = unconditioned_sf.apply(lambda c: (c / c.loc[df.loc[c.name, 'T']]).clip_upper(1))

# simple case, users pay $30 a month (and your units of survival function are "months"
CLV = (30 * conditioned_sf).sum(0)

# more complicated: they each have a different "rate"
CLV = conditioned_sf.sum(0) * rate_by_user

# and so on...
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this. I have added some code by going thru some posts and suggested by you. Modifications I have added in the question itself. I would like the know the output significance(which has been mentioned in the question). And secondly what is the next step post this? Or is it the LTV?